# Is CSS content property SEO friendly?

Tags: html, css, seo

Is CSS content property bad from SEO point of view, do search engines really scan the words which are injected using `:before` and `:after` selectors?

Take this example :

Mr.A uses CSS `content` property to embed the question tag in `h1`, so my question is do search engines scan that word in my `h1` tag? am pretty much sure they don't.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/nX9XQ/)

```
<h1 class="CSS">Pure CSS Menu</h1>
<h1 class="HTML">Structure And Symantics</h1>

.CSS:before {
    content: 'CSS : ';
}

.HTML:before {
    content: 'HTML : ';
}
```

Comment: I'd expect the answer to be "no", as most search engine bots do not bother with CSS at all. So the CSS properties will not render or be taken into account.

Comment: @Oded I wonder what if we dump the page with keywords and simply use `display: none;` to fool search engines

Comment: I have heard that Google parses the JavaScript to look for spam sites, so it may very well use the CSS for something. In either case, both resources are downloaded.

Comment: Are you willing to take the chance? I'd expect that something as blatant as that would be picked up, but something more esoteric may get overlooked.

Comment: All are assumptions so thought to throw up this question here, I guess it must be considering inline styles atleast

Comment: Agreed - which is why I haven't given any of these as answers ;)

Comment: Not to mention that screen reader users will most likely not have that content announced.

Comment: @Mr.Alien google will look at your finally rendered page (css/js) to determine if you tried to cheat them. However only the RAW text of the page will be used for the actual indexing. You'd probably be better off reading up on google panda/penguin and checking forums like searchenginewatch or other, than asking this kind of stuff here.

Comment: In what way is this question closed as **Off Topic**?

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Now it's not.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I setup a test page to see if Google actually reads the hidden text as part of the description. Hopefully it'll get indexed soon.

Comment: @Blender If they are crawling the CSS and linking them with the website(That would be real smart) than I think the text should get indexed..

Comment: @Blender Anything about the index result?

Answer (score 6):

No, search engines do not care about what you put inside your css, js, alt tags, or even meta tags (keywords) as far as "positive" rankings go.

They will however try to detect if you are injecting spam, settings h1's with hidden keywords to display:none, setting a white background on white text, etc.

So ..anything not related to pure content, url & title can work against you, but never for you (some blackhats might not agree..).

Comment: as a supplement i would say no, using content in css is not bad as long as you are not trying to trick search engines. Just remember they will also not index the content you inject via css or js.

Comment: Any articles or sources to support your answer, even I feel that injecting text using CSS wont be indexed

Comment: Like you said, it's won't be indexed ..but it will be evaluated. To see if you are hiding keywords from users. Google: SEO + your choice "hidden text" "keyword stuffing" "hidden keywords"

Answer (score -5):

Just use [lynx](http://lynx-win32-version.en.softonic.com/) - That is how the search engines view your web site.

As to the CSS stuff it ignores it but the bits tagged as a header has a higher priority.

See [this pdf](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf) for details about Google SEO.

Comment: What are you basing this on? Any references?

Comment: http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

Comment: for a start and the next question is?

Comment: Well, why not have that as part of the answer? Which I must add, looks hurried.

Comment: @EdHeal: That PDF doesn't mention Lynx or any other console-based web browser (or Chrome's PDF searching isn't working). [This page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=66353) says that Google does parse the CSS to look for search engine spam, so saying that Google's crawler behaves like Lynx isn't really accurate.

Comment: @Oded - Yes it was hurried as it is a Sunday evening. But you can drag a horse to water but you cannot make it drink. I was assuming that the person is capable of looking up the details for himself.

Comment: So, your objection to my pointing out that this is a low quality answer is that it is the weekend?

Comment: @Blender - I did not say that it was 100% - but it is a good starting point to ensure that the search engines are singing from the same hymn sheet. Where would you like the starting point?

Comment: @EdHeal: Well, I'm guessing that the question was asked *because* the OP can't find anything on Google.

Comment: @Oded - No - I just gave a brief answer as it is the weekend. Why not give an answer yourself? I would be en-trawled to your answer.

Comment: Seeing as I only have conjecture, I wouldn't want to post that as an answer. And the time spent on the comments, could have been used for cleaning up the answer, no?

Comment: @Oded - Probably you are right (also it would be kind to mark your edits in the POST and also write an answer for yourself)

Comment: Well i for one am happy to +1 Ed's answer, even if lynx is not relevant to the answer, it's very well known that search engines don't give a hoot about what you put in your css, js, or even meta tags (keywords), or even alt tags. Not quite true ..they do look in there, to punish you, but nothing you can put in there will help your rankings, quite on the contrary :) Title, Url, Content is the only thing that matters ..and maybe a bit of pagerank.

Comment: @Robert - Thank you. Google keeps things close to their chest and hence we need to use lateral thinking to get a good result for searching.

Comment: Well look like someone doesn't like you here as they downed you again ..a pitty. It's true that google does look inside css to detect things like hidden text (display none, white text on white background, ultra small fonts) ..and will punish you accordingly. But that's why to me the lynx response is also the most relevant ..this is where one's focus should be :: on Content

Comment: @Robert: Right, but the question here is about the `content` property, not about SEO tools. This answer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Blender - Underlying the question is what is good for SEO - i.e. quote "Is CSS content property bad from SEO point of view, do search engines" - that I read is I want my web site to be favourable to search engines. Is that the chief objective of the question?

Comment: @Blender the question was "Is CSS content property bad from SEO point of view"

Comment: @Robert: The question is asking if the `content` property is read by search engines as actual text. Even if it is bad, do you have any references to back your claim up?

Comment: No i don't have any references at hand but have been at this game for over 15 years, and if you take the time to google or visit seo specialized forums you'll easily find all the answers you need. Google WILL check your CSS, and WILL parse your JS, however only in the optic of checking if you are trying to cheat them ..at the end of the day, only content & pagerank really matters. Of course there are many other things today that are taken into account: page speed load, image to text ratio, link to text ratio ..but this is no time for a SEO course :)

Comment: @robert - I think that a web site should be able to read by a person that is blind.I think that a web crawler sees your web site in the same way.

Comment: People should just concentrate on providing genuine and interesting content ..if they can't do that, and need to resort to other tactics, they should probably change jobs :) Url, Title, Content, getting people to link to your pages (not link farms), squeezing google pagespeed to the max and using Adsense (keyword tool / traffic estimator) ..is about all you need to get some solid search rankings.

Comment: Google indexes javascript-generated content, so no that's not "how search engines view your site". Your vague statement might have had some validity 10 years ago.