# How could a web spider crawl the content in ::before?

Tags: css, web-crawler, pseudo-element, scrapy, css-content

The content in a pseudo element such as `::before` or `::after` actually not exists in the DOM tree. So, It's impossible to locate it by selector.

The question is, how could I extract the content in it? For example:

```
<div>This is <span></span>n apple.</div>
...
span::before {
    content : "a"
}

shows : This is an apple.
```

But if I extract the text of `div`, I will only get `This is n apple.` without the content in `span::before`.

How could I deal with this problem?

Comment: The same way the browser does? (By parsing and applying the CSS...)

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16003916/is-css-content-property-seo-friendly

Comment: @Mr.Alien No, this is a problem about how to crawl a third-party website contains pseudo elements.

Comment: @nnnnnn Actually, I have tried and failed. After applying the CSS even though the JS, the content in the pseudo elements still not exists in the DOM tree which still leads to location failed.

Answer (score 1):

> How could I deal with this problem?

Honestly, by not using pseudo-elements for this purpose.

A pseudo-element is specifically designed to render content from outside the document tree.

This "generated content", specified by the `content` property of the `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements, is typically used to add purely cosmetic content.

Therefore, there should be no reason for search engines to index generated content.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements

Comment: This, and if you are crawling a third-party site that is using generated content for this sort of thing, well, too bad for you.

Comment: Oh, I can see uses for this. If the content of the DOM tree is actually "apple" (e.g. for identifiers with pictures or something, "apple", "pear" etc) and you want to decorate those with the proper article. Stuff like that. But of course in those cases it's not necessary to scrape the added words.

Comment: @BoltClock points out the problem, I need to crawl a third-party web site. And this, using pseudo-elements to display normal content, is a anti-crawl tech.

Comment: @Mr Lister: Basically, if the content is essential, it should not be generated content.